# how to query virtual table views instead of physical table from oracle?

Tags: oracle, meteor

node: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb

package: https://atmospherejs.com/metstrike/meteor-oracle

error show me:

**Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object**

```
    if(Meteor.isServer) {

  var oracleConn = Meteor.settings["oracle"].connection;
  var oracleConnString = oracleConn["connectString"];

  Oracle.setDefaultOracleOptions(
    {
      connection: {
      user: oracleConn["username"],
      password: oracleConn["password"],
      connectString: oracleConnString["ip"]+":"+oracleConnString["port"]+"/"+oracleConnString["sid"]
      },
      sqlDebug: true,
      strict: true,
      strictAllowOplogAndTriggers: true
    }
  );

}

TestView = new Oracle.Collection("TEST_VIEW");
```